# Laravel recursive relations

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following tables:

```
directories
    id
    parent_directory_id

users
    id

user_directory_access
    directory_id
    user_id
```

Example:

I need to find `directories` with an `id` of `45` that has any recursive parent_directory_id that is present in the `user_directory_access` table that has a `user_id` of `3`

I'd ideally like a user to automatically inherit access to a directory if they have access to any of the parent directories (recursive throughout the hierarchy) so for example if I have access to the root directory I should be allowed access to all children via 1 record stored in the `user_directory_access` table.

What would be a viable solution? I'm open to restructuring if required.

Comment: Is there a fixed limit of how deep the directories can be nested?

Comment: No there is no limits imposed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a map (cached in memcache or a file or in another table) of directory_id and the list of parent_directory_id of its parents, so for this structure:

```
1
┣━━━2
┃   ┗━━━4
┃       ┗━━━5
┗━━━3
```

Your map would look like this:

```
$parents_map = [
    1 => [],
    2 => [1],
    3 => [1],
    4 => [2, 1],
    5 => [4, 2, 1],
];
```

Whenever you add a new child directory, look up the parents_map of its own parent and add it to the map:

```
// new directory 6 whose parent is 3:
$new_id = 6;
$parent_id = 3;
$parents_map[$new_id] = array_merge([$parent_id], $parents_map[$parent_id]);
```

Then when you need to check the permissions for a directory, look it up in the map and see if any of its parents have permission.

```
$directory_id = 6;
foreach($parents_map[$directory_id] as $parent_id) {
    check_permissions($user_id, $parent_id);
}
```